# Magento 1 - Configurable.js - can it be removed from Simple Product page?

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I'm trying to remove stuff from Magento 1 product page. The page loads in /varien/configurable.js into it. It is a simple product, so there shouldn't be configurable.js on it from what I understand.

I've looked around and don't see any errors on the page after I removed it.

I added it back into:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
    <reference name="head">
         <action method="addJs">
            <script>varien/configurable.js</script>
            <params>defer</params>
        </action>
    </reference> 
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

Are there any downsides from removing it on Simple product page like I did? Does anybody have knowledge about what configurable.js actually do on simple product page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no downside to removing it. If you're trying to improve the seo of the page you can also use merge js logic that is built in Magento (under configuration->advanced settings).

Comment: I'm not sure what configurable.js actually does. I assume this is connected to configurable products, but does it affect simple products?

Comment: configurable.js add swatches and manage showing of all options you have added on configurable product.